# Getting Paypal TransactionID from Ebay API

Tags: java, paypal, ebay-api

Although this question has been posted many times, none of the posted solutions seem to work.

Specifically, it was mentioned that the only way to get the **PayPal Transaction ID** is by calling **GetItemTransactions** on a given item, and retrieving **Transaction.ExternalTransation.ExternalTransactionID**; **DetailLevel** must be set to **RETURN_ALL**.

I've tried this, and it keeps returning a null ExternalTransaction. Does anyone know if I'm missing something? Perhaps there's another way of obtaining the **PayPal Transaction ID** from the Ebay API?

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SdkException {
    ItemTransactions itemTxns = new ItemTransactions();
    GetItemTransactionsCall call = new GetItemTransactionsCall(apiContext);
    GetItemTransactionsRequestType request  = new GetItemTransactionsRequestType();
    request.setDetailLevel(new DetailLevelCodeType[]{DetailLevelCodeType.RETURN_ALL});
    request.setItemID("283891330636");
    //call.setItemID("283891330636");
    GetItemTransactionsResponseType response = (GetItemTransactionsResponseType) call.execute(request);

    //throws IndexOutOfBoundsException, and is null when examining in debug window
    log.debug(response.getTransactionArray().getTransaction()[0].getExternalTransaction()[0]);
}
```

Any help is appreciated, as I'm pretty desperate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! After all this searching, I found a newer Ebay API - the **Sell API**, that can return orders in JSON format, and it also includes the PayPal Txn ID.

Truth be told, I've already attempted to access this API more than a year ago, when I needed to update inventory. At the time though, my requests didn't work, and I was told that API only works with listings created thru that same API itself. However, it seems that it now supports older listings as well.